# Filtering pandas data frame based on different entries in a column (list of comma-separated strings)

Tags: python, pandas, string, filter

I have a Pandas DataFrame where I want to filter for all "IDs" that have different entries in "TCK" (list of comma-separated strings), i.e. are not the same for all entries.

My DataFrame looks likes this:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"ID": [1, 2, 3, 4],
        "TCK": [["AA, AA, AC"], ["LL, LL"], ["DD , DB, DF, DE"], ["LO , LO, LO, LO, LO, LO"]]})
```

The desired output should look like this:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"ID": [1, 3],
        "TCK": [["AA, AA, AC"],["DD , DB, DF, DE"]]})
```

I know that one way would be to first split the strings into new columns (based on commas) and then use a loop to identify the different tickers. However, since there would also be np.nans, this would be a rather complicated solution.

Does anyone know a speedy and elegant solution to this problem?

Comment: you write you have "lists of comma separated strings" but your input is just one string in each list. Could you clarify?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may first split your strings and apply `set` to check if the set has more than 1 element, i.e., has different elements:

```
tck = df1.TCK.apply(lambda x: [item.strip() for item in x[0].split(',')])
df1[tck.apply(lambda x: len(set(x)) > 1)]
```

Comment: maybe to make it a bit more performant, directly create a set instead of creating a list int he first place and run apply again
tck = df1.TCK.apply(lambda x: {item.strip() for item in x[0].split(',')}) or directly tck = df1.TCK.apply(lambda x: len({item.strip() for item in x[0].split(',')}) > 1)

Answer (score 0):

Using `str.extractall`:

```
m = df1['TCK'].str[0].str.extractall('(\w+)')[0].groupby(level=0).nunique().gt(1)

df1[m]
```

output:

```
   ID                TCK
0   1       [AA, AA, AC]
2   3  [DD , DB, DF, DE]
```

Answer (score 0):

using `regex`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"ID": [1, 2, 3, 4],
        "TCK": [["AA, AA, AC"], ["LL, LL"], ["DD , DB, DF, DE"], ["LO , LO, LO, LO, LO, LO"]]})

df['TCK'] = [','.join(l) for l in df['TCK']]
df['TCK']= df['TCK'].replace(r'(\w+)(?:\W+\1\b)+$', None, regex=True)
df.dropna(inplace=True)
print(df.head())
```

output:

```
   ID              TCK
0   1       AA, AA, AC
2   3  DD , DB, DF, DE
```